# A set of divergent integrals that I think, equal to $-\gamma$

Tags: regularization, divergent-integrals, euler-mascheroni-constant

So, we take $\frac{\text{sgn}(x-1)}{x}$ and apply $\mathcal{L}_t[t f(t)](x)$ four times. The transform is known to keep area under the curve. These integrals, I think, are equal to minus Euler-Mascheroni constant. Since they all have infinite parts that cancel each other, their values are finite. I have already [applied Laplace transforms](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385813/can-we-meaningfully-ascribe-values-to-these-divergent-integrals) to regularize divergent integrals in a similar way.

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\text{sgn}(x-1)}{x}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{2 e^{-x}-1}{x}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{x-1}{x (x+1)}dx=\int_0^\infty \left(2 e^x \text{Ei}(-x)+\frac{1}{x}\right) dx=$$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2-2 x \log (x)-1}{(x-1)^2 x} dx=-\gamma$$

Yes?

[image]

Proof: take 2 of them and find average:

$$\int \frac12\left(\frac{x-1}{x (x+1)}+ \left(2 e^x \text{Ei}(-x)+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)dx=-\gamma$$

[image]

Right?

Answer (score 1):

There might be a mistake here, but formally I'm getting

\begin{align}
\int_{x=0}^{x=\infty} \frac{\mathrm{sgn}(x-1)}{x} \mathrm{d}x
&= \int_{x=1}^{x=\infty} \frac{1}{x} \mathrm{d}{x} - \int_{x=0}^{x=1} \frac{1}{x} \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{y^{-1}=1}^{y^{-1}=\infty} \frac{1}{y^{-1}} \mathrm{d}y^{-1} - \int_{x=0}^{x=1} \frac{1}{x} \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{y=1}^{y=0} y \mathrm{d}y^{-1} - \int_{x=0}^{x=1} \frac{1}{x} \mathrm{d}x \\
&= -\int_{y=1}^{y=0} y y^{-2} \mathrm{d}y - \int_{x=0}^{x=1} \frac{1}{x} \mathrm{d}x \\
&= -\int_{y=1}^{y=0} \frac{1}{y} \mathrm{d}y - \int_{x=0}^{x=1} \frac{1}{x} \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{y=0}^{y=1} \frac{1}{y} \mathrm{d}y - \int_{x=0}^{x=1} \frac{1}{x} \mathrm{d}x \\
&= 0
\end{align}

Comment: @Anixx How do you get that change of variable?

Comment: Sorry, typo. Here are some examples why change of variables does not work with divergent integrals with improper bounds: $$I=\int_0^\infty1dx=2\int_0^\infty1du=2I,$$ $$\int_1^{+\infty}\frac1x dx=\int_2^{+\infty}\frac1u du$$ (with substitution $u=2x$). In the second case even the regularized value changes.

Comment: On the other hand, the transforming with Laplace transform as indicated in the question usually works well.

Comment: @Anixx The first line is true though, since $I = 0$. I don't know what's the justification for the second equality in the first line though, unless you already know that the integrals are 0.

Comment: No, $I\ne 0$ of course. Its regularized value is $0$, yes, but as a divergent integral it is definitely not zero.

Comment: @Anixx Are we not working in the context of regularization and divergent integrals?

Comment: @Anixx The second example makes more sense, though.

Comment: Not exactly. I treat divergent integrals as (infinite) entities. The change of variables is not applicable to divergent (to infinity) integrals with improper bounds (and the regularized value also can change). This is not surprising, because they do not satisfy the requirements of change-of-variable theorems.

Comment: Look also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4075766/why-is-ln-0-ne-ln-infty Here I separately transformed $\int_0^1 1/x dx$ and $\int_1^\infty 1/x dx$ and found that the difference between them is $\gamma$. From this it directly follows that their infinite parts cancel out and $\int_0^\infty \frac{\text{sign} (x-1)}x  dx=-\gamma$

Comment: @Anixx I'll check that out.

Comment: The question of substitution of variables in divergent integrals has been raised by me here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3892992/is-there-a-solid-reason-why-some-people-assume-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calcul

Comment: Here is another post regarding regularization of divergent integrals using Laplace transform: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385813/can-we-meaningfully-ascribe-values-to-these-divergent-integrals and this result is actually supported by the theory of hyperfunctions, for instance.

Comment: @Anixx I'll check that out as well. I'd delete the second equation of that question though, since $I = 0$ in the context of regularized integrals, so $I = 2I$ is true.

Comment: No, I am not talking in the context of regularized values (even if finding the regularized value is the aim).

Comment: @Anixx If you're not looking for regularizations, then I don't know what to tell you. The integrals are simply divergent, then.

Comment: And regularization of an integral that has its divergent parts cancel out is different than regularization of an integral that diverges to infinity. For instance, it is okay for me to say $\int_0^\infty (x-\frac2{x^3})dx=0$, but totally not okay to say $\int_0^\infty1dx=0$ or $\int_0^\infty 1/x^2dx=0$ (the later two integrals are equal though).

Comment: You can look here for more on the framework I work in: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115743/an-algebra-of-integrals/342651#342651

Comment: @Anixx It's perfectly okay to say $\int_0^\infty dx = 0$, if you're willing to extend the integral beyond its usual domain. The reason is that $\int_0^\infty dx = \int_0^\infty \lim_{\varepsilon \downarrow 0} e^{-x \varepsilon} (1 - x \varepsilon) dx \stackrel{!}{=} \lim_{\varepsilon \downarrow 0} \int_0^\infty e^{-x \varepsilon} (1 - x \varepsilon) dx = 0$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327812) for details.

Comment: I do not contest that the regularized value of this integral is zero. But it is infinite, hence, not zero. In my framework this integral is an important constant. I use a special symbol for it. $\int_0^\infty dx=\int_0^\infty \frac1{x^2}dx=\tau$

Comment: If you look at the linked page you will see that there are divergent integrals equal to $2\tau, \tau/2, \tau+1/2, \tau-1/2, \tau^2, \tau^3$ and so on.

Comment: It seems, there is a fundamental difference between various regularization methods: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391387/did-anyone-ever-propose-the-distinction-between-divergent-to-infinity-as-oppos